# Sprite Kit Game - storyboard yes or no?

Tags: storyboard, sprite-kit

I am making Sprite kit game with several scenes including logo screen, main menu, other menus and 2 playing scenes. Should I use storyboard? I did it with pure code for each scene, but I have problems with releasing scenes after transitions. Will using storyboard fix these problems, or not?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with storyboards.

When you need to switch to another ViewController (by segue), just remove `SKView` from view hierarchy. This will release your `SKScene`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    [self.skView removeFromSuperview];
    self.skView = nil;
}
```

Note that in this case you'll need to manually add `SKView` to view hierarchy every time the ViewController is about to appear:

```
if (!self.skView.window) {
    [self.view addSubview:self.skView];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So every scene will have its own view controller (ideally) for underlying process. I am right?

Comment: It depends on your requirements. What are other scenes suppose to do?

Comment: Few of them are different menus, two of them are game scenes (but different games), one for achievements and scoreboard. So I think, all menus could be inside one controller, rest of them will have its own one.